# Android image overlay effect

Tags: java, android, image, overlay

I want to create overlay effect with two images. One image is loading from gallery and second image with noise effect must applying when first is loaded.
This my code in onViewCreated in Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    String picturePath = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("image");

    int targetWidth = 600;
    int targetHeight = 400;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

    //first decode image dimensions only - not the image bitmap itself
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);

    //image width and height before sampling
    int currHeight = options.outHeight;
    int currWidth = options.outWidth;

    //variable to store new sample size
    int sampleSize = 1;

    //calculate the sample size if the existing size is larger than target size
    if (currHeight>targetHeight || currWidth>targetWidth)
    {
        //use either width or height
        if (currWidth>currHeight)
            sampleSize = Math.round((float)currHeight/(float)targetHeight);
        else
            sampleSize = Math.round((float)currWidth/(float)targetWidth);
    }

    //use the new sample size
    options.inSampleSize = sampleSize;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;

    //get the file as a bitmap
    Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, options);


    imageView.setImageBitmap(img);
}
```

For example, i have this image (i can't load more than 2 images)
and have image with noise: [Image with effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyvTJ.jpg)
and i want to create something like this [Created image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93YDI.jpg)
Is it possible and if possible can help me ?

Comment: search query for you: "canvas matrix android", best way to achieve your goal is to multiply two bitmaps on `Canvas` (overriden `onDraw` method). This suggestion is all I can do, never tried ;)

Comment: You can use GPUImage Library and add Blend